# How can I solve this fatal error in my microweber/screen package that I installed in my php project?

Tags: php, phantomjs, screenshot, screen-capture

I try to use https://packagist.org/packages/microweber/screen this PHP package, I just installed it in my project and I run the index.php file but there is an error : Any idea ?

**Here is my code in my index.php file:**

```
$url = 'https://github.com';

$screenCapture = new Capture($url);
$screenCapture->setWidth(1200);
$screenCapture->setHeight(800);
$fileLocation = 'files';
$screenCapture->save($fileLocation);
echo $screenCapture->getImageLocation();
```

**Here is the error I had received:**

```
[15-Feb-2023 20:51:43 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Screen\Exceptions\PhantomJsException: sh: 
/home/bloggors/capturewebpage.bloggors.com/vendor/microweber/screen/bin/phantomjs: Permission denied in 
/home/bloggors/capturewebpage.bloggors.com/vendor/microweber/screen/src/Capture.php:259
Stack trace:
#0 /home/bloggors/capturewebpage.bloggors.com/controller/index.php(12): Screen\Capture->save('files')
#1 /home/bloggors/capturewebpage.bloggors.com/router.php(46): include_once('/home/bloggors/...')
#2 /home/bloggors/capturewebpage.bloggors.com/router.php(7): route('/', 'controller/inde...')
#3 /home/bloggors/capturewebpage.bloggors.com/routes.php(14): get('/', 'controller/inde...')
#4 {main}
  thrown in /home/bloggors/capturewebpage.bloggors.com/vendor/microweber/screen/src/Capture.php on line 259
```

Any help will be of great help to me ☺

Comment: `Permission denied` seems to mean you do not have permission to write wherever your trying to save the file.

Comment: @MatteoTassinari What should i do in this case?

Comment: Give your webserver account permission to write to the folder

Comment: @ADyson I have already given the file "files" permission 755 to write. But it doesn't work.

Comment: You'd prolly want to change that to `0775` so the group has write permissions as well, rather than only the owner

Comment: Is `files` a username? I doubt your PHP/Apache server runs under that account

Comment: @DarkBee I can only write it in : 755
Please look at this link you will see: https://ibb.co/BNDk8Tp

Comment: @ADyson No. This is the name of the file in my project.

Comment: So which account did you grant the permissions to?

Comment: @ADyson No. I just put my "files" file in 755 only.

Comment: Do note that it's possible that the user running the `PHP` process could not be the same user as the owner of the folders/files

Comment: Sorry but "No" isn't a meaningful answer to "which account did you grant the permissions to"... that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I don't understand. Can you explain in depth how to give permission please?

Because in my side I just give permission to my files in my project.

Comment: Well yeah, read my comments. You gave write permissions to the owner, not to the group. As an example, a fairly common set-up is that the user called `www-data` is running the `PHP` process, whilst the owner could be someone like `examplecom` but either of them are assigned to the same group, e.g. `psacln` when using plesk.

Comment: Normally you go to the command-line and use the chmod command. Part of that involves specifying which user you are giving the permissions to. In Linux, the webserver will run as a specific user account, which isn't an account used by a human.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for the clarification. But unfortunately I am currently using a shared hosting plan. I don't have that permission to go into the line command. What do you advise me to do in this case?

Comment: @ADyson If I used a vps plan. Can you show me exactly how I can give 0775 permission to my "files" file please?

Comment: At least first try granting the write permission to the group, as DarkBee said, and see if that helps

Comment: ^This. According to your screenshot you would just need to tick the checkbox "write" in the column "group" to assign `0775`. If that doesn't work I'd advice you to open a ticket with the VPS support

Comment: @DarkBee For permission. Is it in the phantomjs file or in the bin folder of phatomjs do I have to give this permission?

I tried to give it. It is still in 644. What to do?

Comment: You'd need to grant it on the "files" folder where you are trying to save the files to. It seemed you already understood that part?

Comment: @ADyson I put it in 775 but it does not work and it gives me the same error what should I do?

Here is the proof: https://ibb.co/pbhxh1f